# How can you remove a quote from a list?

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

I'm making a `discord.py` bot for a friend of mine. I'd like to make it so that you can add silly quotes to a list and then have them randomly selected. That much, I've accomplished.

However, I would also like to be able to remove quotes that are irrelevant, mispelled, etc. I was wondering how one would accomplish this.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
import random
import pickle
import os

Client = discord.Client()
bot_prefix = "."
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=bot_prefix)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot Online!")
    print("Name: {}".format(bot.user.name))
    print("ID: {}".format(bot.user.id))

class Main_Commands():
    def __init__(self, bot):
     self.bot = bot

# .addquote
@bot.command(pass_context = True)
async def addquote(ctx, *answer):
    answer=" ".join(answer)
    if not os.path.isfile("quote_file.pk1"):
        quote_list = []
    else:
        with open("quote_file.pk1", "rb") as quote_file:
            quote_list = pickle.load(quote_file)
    quote_list.append(answer)
    with open("quote_file.pk1", "wb") as quote_file:
        pickle.dump(quote_list, quote_file)
    await bot.say('Quote: "{}" added!'.format(answer))

# .quote
@bot.command(pass_context = True)
async def quote(ctx):
    with open("quote_file.pk1", "rb") as quote_file:
        quote_list = pickle.load(quote_file)
    await bot.say(random.choice(quote_list))

bot.run("TOKEN")
```

Basically, I'd like to add another function, `.removequote()` that would be able to remove a specific quote, while keeping the others intact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove quotes is very similar to add quote, only one line needs replacing. Instead of .append, use a list comp to filter out the unwanted quote. Everything else can remain the same.

```
# .removequote
@bot.command(pass_context = True)
async def removequote(ctx, *answer):
    answer=" ".join(answer)
    if not os.path.isfile("quote_file.pk1"):
        quote_list = []
    else:
        with open("quote_file.pk1", "rb") as quote_file:
            quote_list = pickle.load(quote_file)

    # This line:
    quote_list = [quote for quote in quote_list if quote != answer]

    with open("quote_file.pk1", "wb") as quote_file:
        pickle.dump(quote_list, quote_file)
    await bot.say('Quote: "{}" deleted!'.format(answer))
```

Per server pickling, you can have a different file name for each server, or use a dict for your pickle (personally, I think storing in a separate file is more efficient since you won't have to load other server's quotes):

```
# .removequote
@bot.command(pass_context = True)
async def removequote(ctx, *answer):
    answer=" ".join(answer)
    filename = "quote_file_{}.pkl".format(ctx.message.server.id)
    if not os.path.isfile(filename):
        quote_list = []
    else:
        with open(filename, "rb") as quote_file:
            quote_list = pickle.load(quote_file)

    quote_list = [quote for quote in quote_list if quote != answer]

    with open(filename, "wb") as quote_file:
        pickle.dump(quote_list, quote_file)
    await bot.say('Quote: "{}" deleted!'.format(answer))
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to make a separate list per server?

Comment: @Lemon Separate pickle files based on which server a message comes from, or store the information in a database of some kind (and store originating-server-location information along with the quote itself).